# if else inside if else sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement

Do you know why ELSE is higlihted in my code? Last ELSE. Im trying to create procedure but i have problem with if clause

Can somebody help me? I'm aware that solution with max value of id and adding 1 to it is not good but it is temporary. Later i will try to implement better way

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dodajAuto
    (@marka VARCHAR, 
     @model VARCHAR, 
     @kolor VARCHAR, 
     @moc INT, 
     @dataProdukcji DATETIME, 
     @cena DECIMAL, 
     @typ VARCHAR, 
     @przebieg INT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tmpMarka VARCHAR = (SELECT MARKA FROM MARKA WHERE MARKA=MARKA)
    DECLARE @tmpModel VARCHAR = (SELECT MODEL FROM MODEL WHERE MODEL=MODEL)

    DECLARE @tmpIdModelu INT = (SELECT IDMODELU FROM MODEL WHERE MODEL=MODEL)
    DECLARE @tmpIdMarki INT = (SELECT IDMARKI FROM MARKA WHERE MARKA=MARKA)

    DECLARE @tmpLastIdSamochodu INT = (SELECT MAX(IDSAMOCHODU) FROM SAMOCHOD)
    DECLARE @tmpLastIdModelu INT = (SELECT MAX(IDMODELU) FROM MODEL)
    DECLARE @tmpLastIdMarki INT = (SELECT MAX(IDMARKI) FROM MARKA)


    IF (@tmpMarka IS NOT NULL)
        IF (@tmpModel IS NOT NULL)
            INSERT INTO SAMOCHOD 
            VALUES (@tmpLastIdSamochodu+1, @tmpIdModelu, @kolor, @moc, @przebieg, @dataPRodukcji, @typ);
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO MODEL 
            VALUES (@tmpLastIdModelu+1, @tmpIdMarki, @model, @cena)

    SET @tmpIdModelu = (SELECT IDMODELU FROM MODEL WHERE MODEL = MODEL)

    INSERT INTO SAMOCHOD 
    VALUES (@tmpLastIdSamochodu+1, @tmpIdModelu, @kolor, @moc, @przebieg, @dataProdukcji, @typ);

    ELSE --THIS IS WHERE SYNTAX IS HIGLIHTED, 

    INSERT INTO MARKA VALUES (@tmpLastIdMarki+1, @marka)

    SET @tmpIdMarki  = (SELECT IDMARKI FROM MARKA WHERE MARKA = MARKA)

    INSERT INTO MODEL 
    VALUES (@tmpLastIdModelu+1, @tmpIdMarki, @model, @cena)

    SET @tmpIdModelu = (SELECT IDMODELU FROM MODEL WHERE MODEL = MODEL)

    INSERT INTO SAMOCHOD 
    VALUES (@tmpLastIdSamochodu+1, @tmpIdModelu, @kolor, @moc, @przebieg, @dataProdukcji, @typ);
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense at all.  You have way bigger problems, such as `MODEL = MODEL`.

Comment: Also, why the `;` in the end of  `INSERT` statements in `IF-ELSE` Block?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length) - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: You should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters - if you don't, then your parameters are ***EXACTLY*** one character long - typically *not* what you want !!

Comment: I highlighted (by properly **indenting** your code) what is happening - if you want to have *more than one statement* after an `IF`, you **must** enclose those statements in `BEGIN ..... END` - otherwise **only** one (the next) statement is inside the `IF` clause

Answer (score 3):

`if` and `else` only apply to the single statement after them. If you have a multi-step operation to perform group them with `begin;` and `end;`.

Always declare the size for `varchar()` and `nvarchar()` data types, and the precision and scale for `decimal()` and `numeric()` data types.

[Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length) - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

```
create procedure dodajAuto(
    @marka varchar(30)
  , @model varchar(30)
  , @kolor varchar(30)
  , @moc int
  , @dataProdukcji datetime
  , @cena decimal(18,0)
  , @typ varchar(30)
  , @przebieg int)
as
  begin;
  set nocount, xact_abort on;

  declare @tmpMarka varchar(30) = (select marka from marka where marka=@marka);
  declare @tmpModel varchar(30) = (select model from model where model=@model);

  declare @tmpIdModelu int = (select idmodelu from model where model=@model);
  declare @tmpIdMarki int = (select idmarki from marka where marka=@marka);

  declare @tmpLastIdSamochodu int = (select max(idsamochodu) from samochod);
  declare @tmpLastIdModelu int = (select max(idmodelu) from model);
  declare @tmpLastIdMarki int = (select max(idmarki) from marka);

  if (@tmpMarka is not null)
    if (@tmpModel is not null)

        insert into samochod values (@tmpLastIdSamochodu+1, @tmpIdModelu, @kolor, @moc, @przebieg, @dataprodukcji, @typ);
    else
      begin;
        insert into model values (@tmpLastIdModelu+1, @tmpIdMarki, @model, @cena);
        set @tmpIdModelu = (select idmodelu from model where model=@model);
        insert into samochod values (@tmpLastIdSamochodu+1, @tmpIdModelu, @kolor, @moc, @przebieg, @dataProdukcji, @typ);
      end;
  else
    begin;
      insert into marka values (@tmpLastIdMarki+1, @marka);
      set  @tmpIdMarki  = (select idmarki from marka where marka=@marka);
      insert into model values (@tmpLastIdModelu+1, @tmpIdMarki, @model, @cena);
      set @tmpIdModelu = (select idmodelu from model where model=@model);
      insert into samochod values (@tmpLastIdSamochodu+1, @tmpIdModelu, @kolor, @moc, @przebieg, @dataProdukcji, @typ);
    end;
  end;
go
```

Comment: In this code I got error about ';' near end on the end ang 'go' is highlited

Comment: Ok. There was a luck of another end on the end. Now works fine. thanks a lot ;)